# Python variable not recognized in if-statement

Tags: python, variables, if-statement, while-loop

Here is all the code, but in main(), a while loop checks if on_title_screen is true, and if it is, displays the title screen, but if not, displays the game. However, after starting the program, running the game, and returning to the title screen, attempting to press the start button makes both the code for if on_title_screen==True and elif on_title_screen==False run when only the first bit should run.

```
import random
import pygame
from pygame import *
import math
import sys

#Presets for window
size=width,height=500,500
Ag=-9.80665
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
white=(255,255,255)
blue=(0,0,255)
red=(255,0,0)
gray_bgColor=(190,193,212)

#Initialise pygame Surface as screen
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Flappy Bird Replica")


def falling_loop():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_UP:
                preset.vY=-10
    if preset.yPos>height-50:
        preset.on_title_screen=True
    preset.vY+=1
    preset.yPos+=preset.vY

class presets():
    #Holds all the "global" values for the game
    vY=0
    xPos,yPos=200,100
    on_title_screen=True

class graphics():
    #Holds the methods for loading/displaying graphics
    def load_images(self):
        #Loads the background and sprite images
        self.background_image=pygame.image.load("flappy_background.png").convert()
        self.bird_image=pygame.image.load("flappy_sprite.jpg").convert()
        self.bird_image.set_colorkey(white)
        self.birdHitBox=self.bird_image.get_rect()
    def show_background(self):
        #blits the background
        screen.blit(self.background_image,[0,0])
    def show_bird(self):
        #blits the bird onto screen at xPos, yPos
        screen.blit(self.bird_image,[preset.xPos,preset.yPos])
    def refresh_display(self):
        #updates the display
        screen.blit(self.background_image,[0,0])
        falling_loop()
        self.show_bird()

class titleScreen():
    #Holds the methods for the title screen/menu
    def title(self):
        #Sets up the title
        titleText="Flappy Game"
        titlePos=(0,0)
        currentFont=pygame.font.SysFont("arialms",30,bold=True,italic=True)
        renderTitle=currentFont.render(titleText,1,blue,gray_bgColor)
        self.titlex,self.titley=currentFont.size(titleText)
        screen.blit(renderTitle,titlePos)
    def start(self):
        #Sets up the start Button
        startText="Start Game"
        self.startPos=(0,self.titley)
        currentFont=pygame.font.SysFont("arialms",25,bold=False,italic=False)
        renderStart=currentFont.render(startText,1,blue,gray_bgColor)
        self.startx,self.starty=currentFont.size(startText)
        self.start_rect = pygame.Rect(self.startPos[0],self.titley,self.startx,self.starty)
        screen.blit(renderStart,self.startPos)
    def quit(self):
        #Sets up the quit button
        quitText="Quit"
        self.quitPos=(0,self.starty+self.titley)
        currentFont=pygame.font.SysFont("arialms",25,bold=False,italic=False)
        renderQuit=currentFont.render(quitText,1,red,gray_bgColor)
        self.quitx,self.quity=currentFont.size(quitText)
        self.quit_rect = pygame.Rect(self.quitPos[0],self.titley+self.starty,self.quitx,self.quity)
        screen.blit(renderQuit,self.quitPos)
    def get_click(self):
        #Gets mouse click and processes outcomes
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                x,y=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                #Tests for start:
                if self.start_rect.collidepoint(x,y):
                    print("start")
                    preset.on_title_screen=False
                    graphicsC.show_background()
                elif self.quit_rect.collidepoint(x,y):
                    print("quit")
                    sys.exit()

#Assign objects to respective classes
preset=presets()        
titleC=titleScreen()
graphicsC=graphics()

def setupTitle():
    #bundles all title_screen functions
    titleC.title()
    titleC.start()
    titleC.quit()

def main():
    graphicsC.load_images()
    graphicsC.show_background()
    setupTitle()
    while True:
        clock.tick(30)
        if preset.on_title_screen==False:
            graphicsC.refresh_display()
            print("working...")
        elif preset.on_title_screen==True:
            setupTitle()
            titleC.get_click()
        pygame.display.flip()

main()
```

Comment: Instead of using a ton of global variables, you should really start using [function arguments and return values](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm) for flow control and variable scoping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `self.xxx` to make class attributes. You also need to make sure those values are defined when initializing the class using the `__init__` method. So use:

```
class presets():
    #Holds all the "global" values for the game
    def __init__(self):
        self.vY=0
        self.xPos,self.yPos=200,100
        self.on_title_screen=True
```

However, making 'global' variables this way probably isn't the best way, as [Cyber mentions in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27129680/python-variable-not-recognized-in-if-statement#comment42758526_27129680).